# Get specific files in a Recursive Directory

Tags: php, recursion, spl

Following a given example by a comment in the php.net manual I am trying to grab each file named file.txt in a recursively directory structure.

```
Folder/
  subfold1
   subfold2
     file.txt

   subfold3
     file.txt
```

etc. is a example on how the folder structure may look like.

```
    $directory = new \RecursiveDirectoryIterator(__DIR__ . '/..');

    $iterator = new \RecursiveIteratorIterator($directory);

    $files = new \RegexIterator($iterator, '/^file.txt$/', \RecursiveRegexIterator::GET_MATCH);

    var_dump($files);
```

The problem is that the given code is giving the following result:

```
object(RegexIterator)#4 (1) { ["replacement"]=> NULL }
```

What should I do with it? I am simply looking for the file and the given path, preferably in an array.

Answer (score 4):

You generally want to *iterate* over the `*Iterator` object, most often using a basic `foreach()` loop.

```
foreach ($files as $file) {
    // Do something
}
```

In your case, the work is a *little* more involved because the code that you are using at the moment will never return any matching files to iterate.  First, let's see what should work.

```
$directory = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator(
    __DIR__ . '/..',
    RecursiveDirectoryIterator::KEY_AS_FILENAME | 
    RecursiveDirectoryIterator::CURRENT_AS_FILEINFO
);
$files = new RegexIterator(
    new RecursiveIteratorIterator($directory),
    '#^file\.txt$#',
    RegexIterator::MATCH,
    RegexIterator::USE_KEY
);
```

The key take-home changes are:

- The `RecursiveDirectoryIterator::KEY_AS_FILENAME` flag for the `RecursiveDirectoryIterator`, used in combination with
- The `RegexIterator::USE_KEY` flag for the RegexIterator`

Previously, as the iterator was being iterated, the regex would be matching against the "current" iterator value which in your case was an `SplFileInfo` object representing each file. When cast to a string, for the regex to do its matching, the `SplFileInfo` objects were turned into their full path; directories and all. This meant that your regex would never match since it is only expecting the file name.

To cut a long story short, the `KEY_AS_FILENAME` and `USE_KEY` flags mean that the regex is working on just the file name for each file. Yay!

You may also notice that I have used the `RegexIterator` in `RegexIterator::MATCH` mode. This means that upon looping over the matched files, we have full access to each `SplFileInfo` object. This gives us much more to play with than just a string with the file name as `RegexIterator::GET_MATCH` would provide.

To print out each of the files, with their full paths, you could use something like:

```
foreach ($files as $file) {
    echo $file->getPathname() . "\n";
}
```

See the [`SplFileInfo` documentation](http://php.net/splfileinfo) for a full list of methods available.